# c# abstract field as a property and as a return from a method

Tags: c#, .net

I've tried and tried but I'm not sure how to even google this.

I've been playing with an abstract class this morning.
What I would like to do is get (only a `get`, forgetting a `set` for now) the `whenused` field of `Salutation` through the `GoodMorning` class ~ but to  access it as a property instead of a method call.

The following code works just fine.  But I'd use `morn.whenUsed` in the Main() instead of `morn.whenUsed()`.

If the same change is necessary in `GoodMorning`, `GoodAfternoon`, and `GoodNight` that is fine.  But I'd like to think the three classes can implement whenUsed differently, but if not then that's fine.

Is this even possible using an abstract?

Thanks for you input.

```
namespace AbstractClas
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Salutation morn = new GoodMorning("beautiful day");
            Salutation aftr = new GoodAfternoon("after lunch comfort food comma");
            Salutation nigh = new GoodNight("light and brezzy night");

            Console.WriteLine("morn is the saluataion used during the {0}.", morn.whenUsed());
            Console.WriteLine("aftr is the saluataion used during the {0}.", aftr.whenUsed().ToUpper());
            Console.WriteLine("nigh is the saluataion used during the {0}.", nigh.whenUsed());

            if (morn is Salutation)
                Console.WriteLine("morn is a Salutation");

            if (morn is GoodMorning)
                Console.WriteLine("morn is a GoodMorning");

            if (morn is GoodAfternoon)
                Console.WriteLine("morn is a GoodAfternoon");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("morn is NOT a GoodAfternoon");

            if (morn is GoodNight)
                Console.WriteLine("morn is a GoodNight");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("morn is NOT a GoodNight");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }


    internal abstract class Salutation
    {
        protected string salutation = "";
        protected string whenused = "";
        internal abstract void salu(string str, string wUsed);
        internal abstract string whenUsed();
    }

    internal class GoodMorning : Salutation
    {
        internal override void salu(string s, string w) { salutation = s; whenused = w; }
        internal GoodMorning(string gm) { salu(gm, "morning".ToUpper()); }
        internal override string whenUsed() { return whenused;  }
    }

    internal class GoodAfternoon : Salutation
    {
        internal override void salu(string s, string w) { salutation = s; whenused = w; }
        internal GoodAfternoon(string ga) {
            char[] c = "afternoon".ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(c);
            salu(ga, new string(c));
        }
        internal override string whenUsed() { return whenused; }
    }

    internal class GoodNight : Salutation
    {
        internal override void salu(string s, string w) { salutation = s; whenused = w; }
        internal GoodNight(string gn) { salu(gn, "night".ToUpper()); }
        internal override string whenUsed() { return whenused.ToLower(); }
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking. Are you looking to change `whenUsed` from a method to a read only property? If so, can't you define it as `internal abstract string whenUsed { get; }` in `Salutation` and override it as `internal override string whenUsed { get { return /*whatever the specific class wants to return*/; } }` ?

Comment: Properties can be overrided in same way as methods

Comment: @KMoussa Your comment shows me you do, very clearly, understand.  I see what I did wrong.  I didn't implement the ` { get; }` as an implementation on the property whenused of Salutation.  Thanks.

Comment: @Fabio Properties can (because they are kind of actually methods) but fields can't.  Would you agree that statement? or how would you but it?

Comment: @user2367083 you're very welcome, added as an answer for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to change `whenUsed` from a method to a read only property, you can define it as

```
 internal abstract string whenUsed { get; }
```

in `Salutation`, and then override it as

```
internal override string whenUsed { get { return /*whatever the specific class wants to return*/; } }
```

in your derived classes